# Obtaining all values in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
   [id] => 1043847
   [company] => Array 
       ( 
          [businesstype] => Array 
                ( 
                   [0] => Array 
                       ( 
                          [id] => 6 
                          [name] => Business Service Provider 
                       )
                   [1] => Array
                       (
                          [id] => 8
                          [name] => Retailer 
                       ) 
                 )
         ) 
  )
```

I would like to be able to get the value of company -> businesstype -> name for all the arrays inside businesstype so it would display like this:

Business Type(s): Business Service Provider, Retailer

Right now if I do this:

```
<?php echo($chamber_member['company']['businesstype']['name']); ?>
```

Nothing happens, if I do this:

```
<?php echo($chamber_member['company']['businesstype'][0]['name']); ?>
```

I get only the one for array [0]. How can I get both values separated by a comma like on the example above? Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!!

Comment: `foreach($chamber_member['company']['businesstype'] as $a) echo $a[0]['name'].", ";`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed with a minor adjustment: foreach($chamber_member['company']['businesstype'] as $a) echo $a['name'].",";

Comment: I post it as an answer for better helping people who have this question. you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($chamber_member['company']['businesstype'] as $a)
    $b[] = $a['name'];
$result = implode(", ", $b);
```

Comment: and what about the last remaining thing `, ` ?

Comment: This one worked for what I needed, I think I may have been using the implode suggestions incorrectly... but this worked great, thank you!!

Comment: @Viral Thankyou for mentioning. fixed.

Comment: @meh this is overkill !!

Comment: @Viral I don't pay attention to that part because it's not the question. these are dozens of ways to do that. you suggest.

Comment: see  the answer by Rizier123, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31546336/3113793)

Comment: @Viral I upvoted him at the beginning. Also changed it to implode.

Answer (score 5):

This should work for you:

First get the column into an array with `array_column()`, then you can simply `implode()` this array ,e.g.

```
echo implode(",", array_column($chamber_member["company"]["businesstype"], "name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take names by array_column and cobine by implode

```
<?php echo implode(',', array_column($chamber_member['company']['businesstype'], 'name')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop into the array position with the 'businesstype' values:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($chamber_member['company']['businesstype']); $i++){

    echo $chamber_member['company']['businesstype'][$i]['name'] . ', ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like `array_column()` but for completeness, just `foreach()`:

```
foreach($chamber_member['company']['businesstype'] as $array) {
    echo $array['name'];
}
```

Or add to an array and `implode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `array_map()`:-

```
$arr=array
(
   'id' => 1043847,
   'company' => array 
       ( 
          'businesstype' => array 
                ( 
                   array 
                       ( 
                          'id'=> 6 ,
                          'name' => 'Business Service Provider' 
                       ),
                   array
                       (
                          'id' => 8,
                          'name' => 'Retailer'
                       ) 
                 )
         ) 
  );

  echo $names = implode(',',array_map( function($person) { return $person['name']; },$arr['company']['businesstype']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. best answer for this..

```
$result=$chamber_member['company']['businesstype'];
$last=end($result);
for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++)
{
$b[$i] = $result[$i]['name']; echo $b[$i]; if($last!=$result[$i]['name']){ echo ","; }

}
```